# CA1813 Avoid unsealed attributes in MVC C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

CA 1813 Avoid unsealed attributes code review error has thrown in the FilterConfig.cs page (which is default page of Model View Controller project). I have added the code Attribute Usage (as per Microsoft suggestion). but code analysis still reports the issue.

Kindly suggest how to solve it.
Please find the code snippet below,

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        // The attribute is valid for type-level targets.
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Delegate)]
        public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                if (filterContext != null)
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
                    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Microsoft suggestion says to *seal the attribute type or make it abstract.*. You didn't do either. You should also name your class `NoCacheAttribute`, but that's just a naming convention.

Comment: First shot in google yields the answer... [CA 1813 Avoid unsealed attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182267.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's written on [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182267.aspx) about `CA 1813 Avoid unsealed attributes` and in the errors content.
Add `sealed` keyword to your `Attribute` class.

```
public sealed class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
```